# Increment number within string.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple image viewer on my page that loads thumbnails underneath. When you click a thumbnail, it just swaps the thumbnail link for the main image by simply removing the thumbnail folder from the url like so:

```
$('#scroller img').on("click",function(){
$('#main-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('t/', ''));
});
```

But I also want people to be able to click on some left and
 right arrows to advance or go back one.

Here is my code for the right arrow:

```
$('#rar').on("click",function(){

 /*$('#main-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace(/(\d+)/, function(){return arguments[1]*1+1} ));*/

$('#main-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace(/\d+/, function(val) { return parseInt(val)+1})); 
});
```

I think the syntax may be wrong. It isn't working anyway. Neither did the failed attempt you can see commented out.

But what I'd really like to do is get the filecount in the image directory and increment the 1 in blah/1.jpg until it reaches the filecount or decrement it until it reaches zero with the left arrow.

My filenames were originally zero padded as 001.jpg, 002.jpg, but i thought that would complicate things even further so I just did away with the padding, unless someone has a simple method with that too.

Simplicity is certainly the key here. I didn't want to have to jump through hoops to simply increase or decrease a damned number.

Any help would be most appreciated as always and thanks for your time in advance ;-)

Comment: you dont need the `replace()` function. the `attr()` method overwrites the old value anyway ;)

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery, but when I searched for _`jquery .replace()`_ in Google, I didn't find any result. I found jQuery's `replaceAll()`, `replaceWith()`, etc. but here was not `.replace()`. So I guess whether it is syntax error or not? I don't know jQuery so if I'm wrong then please correct me.

Comment: It's javascript string replace. Works perfect on the image swap code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `val` should be the second argument in your anonymous function:

```
$('#main-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace(/\d+/, function(_, val) { return (parseInt(val)+1);}));
```

Comment: @Lee instead of `$(this)` try `$('#main-img')` also try `return ("" + (parseInt(val)+1));`

Comment: bloody hell. You know what I've gone and done there don't you? =D staring me in the face now. Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: For anyone else who can't see it, I was using the src of the rightarrow (rar) with $this instead of using the src of the main img.  This arose because I copied and pasted the code from my previous function (to swap images) and didn't catch it.

Comment: Now my problem is that I can't seem to get it to work when checking if the number of the filename is greater than zero. `$('#lar').on("click touchstart",function(){
var num = parseInt( $('#main-img').attr('src'),  10);
if (num > 0) {
 $('#main-img').attr('src',$('#main-img').attr('src').replace(/\d+/, function(val) { return parseInt(val)-1}));
} 
});` think I have mental block today.

Comment: @Lee looks like in your first parse `num` you are trying to parse the `src` you should be only trying to parse the `number` part of the source `/\d+/`...`num` probably = `NAN` after your `parseInt()` call.

Comment: I thought the radix would take care of that. I'll try stripping it down first though. Thanks again!